# RegExp to parse currency value

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I would need to write a RegExp in AS3 which parses an Excel formatted currency value into a number:
E.g.
    RegExp($35,600.00) = 35600

And checks if it is correctly formatted (with the "," as the thousands separator, and the "." as the decimal point. The currency symbol could be any (not just $) and could stand at the beginning or the end.

So I would just need to strip every non digit from the number and check if is valid.

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 8):

You will need two cases, one for comma as separator and another for decimal separated whole numbers.

If a whole number, remove everything after the comma or decimal point(depending on your format).  Then run the following Regex:

This will remove all non-digit characters:

```
s/\D+//g;
```

If you do not have a whole number, you will need to include an exception for the whole number separator:

Decimal separator:

```
 s/[^\d.]+//g
```

Comma separator:

```
 s/[^\d,]+//g
```

*Disclaimer: I only parsed these regexes in my head, so my syntax could be slightly off.

Comment: This will also take care, if I have a comma as the thousands separator and a decimal as the decimal separator?
Somehow AS3 does not like this regex format

Comment: Martin, no experience with AS3 regex formatting, but if you lop off the edges such as s/ and //g+, then take the result of that match.

Comment: @Chris Ballance: yes, your regex syntax was off; check my edit.

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to only keep 3452345.3252345, this keeps ALL decimals, so something like "234.45 U.S. Dollars" gets 'converted' to "234.45.."

Answer (score 2):

After stripping of leading and trailing currency symbols and spaces, you can use the following expression.

```
[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]{2})+
```

That is

```
(
    [1-9][0-9]{0,2}  One to three digits, no leading zero, followed by
    (,[0-9]{3})*     a thousands separator and three digits, zero or more times,
  |                  or
    0                a leading zero.
)
(.[0-9]{2})?         Optional a decimal point followed by exactly two digits.
```

Handling the currency symbol nicely is not the easiest thing because you have to avoid inputs with a leading and a trailing currency symbol. A solution would be using a look ahead assertion.

```
(?=$(([$€] ?)?[0-9,.]+|[0-9,.]+( ?[$€]))^)[$€ ]+<ExpressionFromAbove>[$€ ]+
```

This does the following.

```
(?=                   Positive look ahead assertion.
  $                   Anchor start of line.
  (                   Begin options.
    ([$€] ?)?         Optional leading currency symbol followed by an optional space
    [0-9,.]+          and one or more digits, thousand separators, and decimal points
  |                   or
    [0-9,.]+          one or more digits, thousand separators, and decimal points
    ( ?[$€])          followed by an optional space and and a currency symbol.
  )                   End options.
  ^                   Anchor end of line.
)
[$€ ]+                Leading currency symbol and optional space.
<ExpressionFromAbove> Match the actual number.
[$€ ]+                Trailing optional space and currency symbol.
```

If you know, that the format is correct, strip out everything that is not a digit or a decimal point and parse it into a decimal (in C# this would be using Decimal.Parse()), or, if there is no suitable parsing method, just split at the decimal point, parse into to integers, and combine both numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[$|£|<insert more pipe sepatared options here>]?(\d)*(,)?(\d)*.\d\d[$|£|<insert more pipe sepatared options here>]?
```

Might work.