# Parse and compare currency values

Tags: jquery

I have two divs named with the classes `leased` and `limit`. In each div is a value and I am using jQuery to hide another div, called `#next`, if the value in the `.leased` div is higher than the value in the `.limit` div.

It all works great with the following code, however I plan for the values in the divs to be currencies i.e. `£10,000.00`. As such, the jQuery isn't returning anything.

What do I need to do to the below code in order for it to parse the currency value, please?

```
<div class="limit">£10,000.00</div>
<div class="leased">£11,000.00</div>
<div id="next">next</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#next").toggle(parseInt($(".leased").text(), 10) < parseInt($(".limit").text(), 10));
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegExp to parse currency value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357946/regexp-to-parse-currency-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove the non-numerical characters from the `text()` then run them through `parseFloat()` before making the comparison, like this:

```
var limit = parseFloat($('.limit').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var leased = parseFloat($('.leased').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
$("#next").toggle(leased < limit);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qvvsx9k3/)

Alternatively you could add the plain values to the HTML using `data-*` attributes and perform the logic on those values directly, like this:

```
<div class="limit" data-val="10000.00">£10,000.00</div>
<div class="leased" data-val="11000.00">£11,000.00</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

```js
$("#next").toggle($('.leased').data('val') < $('.limit').data('val'));
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qvvsx9k3/1/)

Comment: That's fantastic Rory, many thanks indeed for sharing. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a ready-made library that can convert currency strings into numbers, like [Numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/)

Otherwise, as suggested in other answers and comments, either remove all non-numeric characters or create a regular expression that potentially (based on your needs) also supports comma as decimal separator, as such syntax is used in some countries.